# Populating FieldArray based on a JSON file uploaded

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I'm trying to populate a FieldArray component, based on the contents of a json file dropped into a react-dropzone.

Using the [example](http://redux-form.com/6.5.0/examples/fieldArrays/) in the docs(as the structure of my code is practically identical). My file would contain a list of members. After the file is dropped/selected, the reducer updates the state of the form. So, in my file, the key "members", is matched to the FieldArray component with the same name.

The logic works for Field components but not the FieldArray component. The issue being that if I have a JSON file with 3 members, the form updates to display 3 members but each member will have no content.

The (edited) code that runs when a file is dropped into the dropzone:

```
onDrop(acceptedFiles) {
  this.setState({ files: acceptedFiles });
  acceptedFiles.forEach((file) => {
  const jsonObj = new XMLHttpRequest();
  jsonObj.overrideMimeType('application/json');
  jsonObj.open('GET', file.preview, true);
  jsonObj.onreadystatechange = () => {
    if (jsonObj.readyState === 4 && jsonObj.status===200) {
      const memberJson = JSON.parse(jsonObj.responseText);
      if (!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(memberJson , 'members')) {
       this.props.onSubmitMembers(memberJson);
    }
  };
  jsonObj.send(null);
});
```

My form construction:

```
const UploadForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'upload',
  destroyOnUnmount: false,
  forceUnregisterOnUnmount: true,
  enableReinitialize: true,
  validate,
  initialValues: {
    members: [{}],
    somethingElse: [{}]
  },
})(SimpleForm);

export default connect(
  (state) => ({ initialValues: state.getIn(['upload', 'data']) }),
  { load: loadMembers},
)(UploadForm);
```

My initial state:

```
const initialState = fromJS({
 data: {
   members: [{}],
   somethingElse: [{}]
  },
  sending: false,
});
```

In my Reducer:

```
case LOAD_MEMBERS:
      return state.update('data', (data) => data.concat(action.payload));
```

Members JSON:

```
{
    "members": [{
            "firstname": "foo",
            "lastname": "bar"
        },

        {
            "firstname": "other",
            "lastname": "other"
        }
    ]
}
```

FieldArray: https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-Kf8QRJd0W0YMKBw-PMo

If it's not clear, I can modify all the code and put it on that webpack site.

Comment: If you're providing `initialValues` from Redux, you should not specify it as a config param to `reduxForm()`, although that _should_ override properly.

Wow, `readyState === 4`, that's hardcore oldskool!

To help you, I'd need to see: 1) your data structure (an example json snippet of members) and 2) your `FieldArray` component.

Comment: Cool, I figured you didn't need to do that. Thank you for informing! I'll update that. I'll update the main post with the snippet and FieldArray component.

PS. hehe the code is mostly from a co-worker who copied it from elsewhere. I guess that's what happens when deadlines are short and you're inexperienced :>

Comment: Yeah, it would be great if the code could actually _run_ on WebpackBin. Nothing immediately obvious is jumping out to me just reading it.

Comment: Someone else is working on it now. I'll update this post, when it gets fixed.

Comment: Oh and fyi, as I'm using 'redux-form/immutable'. I couldn't quite use webpackbin.  If it doesn't get fixed, I'll send over something in github or whatever is easiest. Thank you very much for responding Erik.